# Strange JavaScript comparison operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var quiz_progress = '3'

console.log(+quiz_progress)
console.log($('#quiz .question').length + 1)

console.log(+quiz_progress >= $('#quiz .question').length + 1)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quiz">
  <div class="question">1</div>
  <div class="question">1</div>
  <div class="question">1</div>
</div>
```

Why is this `false`? since I casted the string to number. And try to do `typeof` for both variable, both shows the correct data type.

Comment: Why should `'3' == $('#quiz .question').length + 1` be true? Even if `$('#quiz .question').length + 1` is 3, the result will be still `'3' != 3`

Comment: Because `3 == 4` is `false`?

Comment: `$('#quiz .question').length + 1 = 4` while `+quiz_progress = 3`. How can this two values are the same?

Comment: @SeanVieira take a look, updated my question

Comment: in console `3
4
false` its true that 3 and 4 are not equal. i dont get the upvote though :)

Comment: The updated code with `>=` is testing if `3 >= 4`, which of course is `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are checking if 3 equals 4. You have 3 .question divs, so:

```
$('#quiz .question').length + 1 ==> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

you miss `+` Prefix Increment Operator (++)

```
var quiz_progress = '3'

console.log(++quiz_progress) // 4
console.log($('#quiz .question').length + 1)

console.log(++quiz_progress >= $('#quiz .question').length + 1) // 5 >= 4
```

Comment: i think he wants to change string to int by adding 1 + not increment it

Comment: I think ,OP expects quiz_progress to increase 1.So OP wonder for getting false !!